# Why does graphiql keep showing loading?

Tags: gatsby

When using gatsby , I try seeing available schemes on my gatsby app using the graphiql in built app, but it just keeps showing loading for like forever, what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case was because of the helmet configuration in the server, I follow the next step in my express app to solve the issue:

> app.use(helmet());

is an alias for the following:

```
app.use(helmet.contentSecurityPolicy());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginEmbedderPolicy());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginOpenerPolicy());
app.use(helmet.crossOriginResourcePolicy());
app.use(helmet.dnsPrefetchControl());
app.use(helmet.expectCt());
app.use(helmet.frameguard());
app.use(helmet.hidePoweredBy());
app.use(helmet.hsts());
app.use(helmet.ieNoOpen());
app.use(helmet.noSniff());
app.use(helmet.originAgentCluster());
app.use(helmet.permittedCrossDomainPolicies());
app.use(helmet.referrerPolicy());
app.use(helmet.xssFilter());
```

I had the same problem, so I swapped out the alias for adding each one individually. When I commented out the first two (contentSecurityPolicy & crossOriginEmbedderPolicy), Apollo came back to life.

For the record, commenting out these policies is not recommended for production, but it should unblock anyone who gets stuck here.

It says apollo but also works with express-graphql or similar GUI tools/apps from the backend, thanks for the answer to [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70941687/12900529)